# Not able to retrieve data from req.user using express and passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

[The function I'm authenticating the username and password with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZgf4.jpg)

[The function I am using req.user in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQRHG.jpg)

[The ejs template I'm passing data in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcSQa.jpg)

[error message on browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Xbe.jpg)

[function i'm registering the user with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL3e6.jpg)

I have made a simple user authentication website. I want to show the name of the user on the page after successful login. I am authenticating the user and then want to pass the name of the user through ejs templating. But `req.user` is not passing any data.
I am relatively new to the technology. I have written the `app.use()` functions in correct order. Still I'm not able retrieve data through req.user. Below is the error message shown on browser when i run the app on `localhost`. please help.

```js
//jshint esversion:6

const express=require("express");
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(session({
  secret: "secret",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());



mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/flidDB");
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema =new mongoose.Schema
(
  {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    Proffesion: String,
    stateOfResidence: String,
    mobileNumber: Number,
    username: String,
    Password: String,
    cityOfResidence: String
  }
);

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = new mongoose.model("User",userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});


app.get("/",function(req,res)
{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
}
);
app.get("/login",function(req,res)
{
    if(req.user)
      {
          console.log(req.user);
          res.render("loginHome",{User: req.user.firstName});
      }
    else {
      res.render("login");
    }
}
);
app.get("/:topic",function(req,res)
{
    res.render(req.params.topic);
}
);

app.get("/loginHome",function(req,res)
{
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.render("loginHome");
    } else {
      res.render("login",{User: req.user.firstName});
    }
}
);

app.post("/createaccount",function(req,res)
{
  User.register({firstName: req.body.firstName,
                 lastName: req.body.lastName,
                 Profession: req.body.Profession,
                 stateOfResidence: req.body.stateOfResidence,
                 mobileNumber: req.body.mobileNumber,
                 username:req.body.username,
                 cityOfResidence:req.body.cityOfResidence},req.body.password,function(err,user) {
                   if (err) {
                     console.log(err);
                   } else {
                     passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
                       res.redirect("/loginHome");
                     });
                   }
                 });

               });

app.post("/login",function(req,res)
{
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  req.login(user, function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/loginHome");
      });
    }
  });
});



app.post("/",function(req,res)
{
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});
app.post("/signup",function(req,res)
{
  res.render("signup");
});
app.listen(3000,function()
{
    console.log("server has started successfully!");
}
);
```

Comment: Although your code snippet already contains most of the relevant code, it is generally easier for everyone if you do not share screenshots of your source code, but the code snippets themselves in a preformatted code block. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code for more info.

Comment: Okay, new at the platform. Will surely keep it in mind. thanks.